# Sorting associated table records is not working

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have a `BagEntity` and `ItemsEntity` (simplified). It is my intention to fetch a particular bag with all items associated. This part is working so far.

The problem is that the order of items is determined by its `order` column, but, for some reason, the result is not being sorted.

Please note that I have double checked the actual value of `order` of each record. The values are correct. Further, I have checked the generated SQL-statment which *does not* contain the `ORDER BY` directive.

```js
return await BagEntity.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: ItemsEntity,
      order: [[ItemsEntity, 'order', 'ASC']],
      // order: [['order', 'ASC']],
    }
  ],
  where: { id: bagId },
});
```

I've tried various options [from here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4553) but none of them worked.

#### Expected result

```json
{
  "name": "My bag",
  "items": [
     { order: 0, name: "Some item" },
     { order: 1, name: "Another item" },
     { order: 2, name: "Yet another item" }
   ]
}
```

#### Actual result

```json
{
  "name": "My bag",
  "items": [
     { order: 0, name: "Some item" },
     { order: 2, name: "Yet another item" },
     { order: 1, name: "Another item" }
   ]
}
```

Comment: How does the generated SQL looks like if you use `order` on the root level?